# Two I2C NES mini controllers on the same I2C bus?

Tags: i2c, gamepad

Is it possible to connect two nes i2c nes controllers onto the same i2c bus?

I will guess that is not possible if the `i2c` addresses of these controllers are hard coded to a common value.

Any ideas?

If it can be done, are there any issues to be concerned about?

Thanks

Comment: Your question was not quite clear to me. I have edited it in an effort to move it closer to proper English, but I may have inadvertently changed your meaning. If you feel this may be the case, please write your question in your native language, and then "translate" it to English with [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i2c` is a [*bus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_%28computing%29) in the computer/electronic sense of the word. By definition, a *bus* is designed to support communication between multiple devices.

However, for the `i2c` bus, each "slave device" connected to the *bus* must have a **unique** address. Please review the [fundamentals of the `i2c` protocol](https://www.circuitbasics.com/basics-of-the-i2c-communication-protocol/) if you are not sure about any of these terms - or need a tutorial.

If the `nes i2c nes controller` provides no means that allow you to set or change its default `i2c` address, then you may use only one on a single `i2c` bus. And therefore, if you need a 2nd (or third or fourth, or ...) `nes i2c nes controller`, each of them will need to be assigned to a different `i2c` bus. *Please read on to learn how this may be done:*

Depending on your situation/*use-case*, you may be able to configure other unused GPIO pins as `i2c` buses. If you have an RPi 4 (BCM 2711), this will almost certainly be the case. If you want or need multiple `i2c` buses on a single RPi, you should begin by reading [this documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README) - also available on your local filesystem at `boot/overlays/README`.

Having read that document, you will understand that the RPi provides you the ability to configure multiple `i2c` buses through its [***device tree***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devicetree) facility, and specifically through the capacity of modifiers known as ***device tree overlays*** (a.k.a. `dtoverlay`) to modify the default hardware configuration. This is *easily accomplished* by adding **existing** dtoverlays to the `/boot/config.txt` file on your RPi.

Consequently, I feel this is the answer to your question:

##### Answer: "Configure an additional `i2c` bus in `/boot/config.txt` by using one of the `dtoverlay` definitions in `boot/overlays/README`

Please try this. If you have any specific questions regarding choice or usage of a specific `dtoverlay`, it may be best to ask those as new questions, but you may also submit a Comment, or edit your original question. ALSO: If you have specific questions, **please include your RPi model # and your kernel version!**

Comment: you could also use an I2C multiplexer

Comment: @Bravo: True - do you have an example? Or maybe better, describe that in your answer? :)

Comment: No example - I read a comment in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/130523/multiple-temp-humidity-sensors-40-feet-apart that mentioned such a thing. I have seen them used (on arduino type devices admittedly) but never used them myself. I can imagine it may complicate things - but if you have only one i2c bus at your disposal, it's the only way to do it :p

Comment: @Bravo: `but if you have only one i2c bus...`    But that's not the case for the RPi. All of them have at least two `i2c` buses, and RPi 4 has 6 `i2c` buses **and** "From the 5.4 kernel onwards the base DT includes the use of i2c_mux_pinctrl" - which I *think* means RPi has an internal mux in the the device tree (pin config) now. That said, OP didn't disclose RPi model or kernel ver, but most importantly *I've never used it, & can't prepare a reliable answer*.

Comment: @Bravo: I do appreciate your comments, though. As it turns out there are I2C Muxes, and there are also I2C Switches - which accomplish the same thing in different ways. [link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+an+I2C+multiplexer+switch&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web)

Comment: Hi thanks you've confirmed my expectation. This was't an RPI question - more a general question. Thanks folk

Comment: @johnlon: `This was't an RPI question - more a general question.` That hadn't occurred to me until I read your comment, but it seems I've made another *bad assumption*. In any case: **1)** `i2c` on RPi has several *unique* features, **2)** Glad you found this useful, and **3)** [please read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I bitbanged the protocol for fun (not profit).

Implementation is :
https://github.com/Johnlon/NESInterfaceAndPeripherals/blob/main/README.md

Hackaday:
https://hackaday.io/project/181036-nes-controller-interface-using-pic16f18446

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5Velt4mQLk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113615)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).